# Recording streaming with vlc in c++

Tags: c++, streaming, vlc, libvlc

I would like to record from streaming and save on the computer with vlc in c++ can anybody help me get started maybe with some code example.I just came accross the libvlc but I can't find no tutorial. Can anybody help me with any code sample to record from streaming?

Comment: since there are no record api in libvlc,maybe you can add it by youself.and you may get some help from this [Add new api to libvlc](https://patches.videolan.org/patch/606/)